# unlink() не удаляет файл

Tags: php, файловая-система

Столкнулся с такой проблемой - unlink не удаляет файл по абсолютному пути: путь верный, файл там есть. Пытался менять каталог через chdir там удалять и возвращать снова старый путь - эффект тот же. Вписывал абсолютный путь вручную - тоже не удаляет. Пытался удалить файл, находящийся в той же директории, что и скрипт - тоже возвращает ошибку.

**Код скрипта img_delete.php:**

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

if (isset($_POST)) {
    $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].substr($_POST['imgPath'], 1, -1);

    if (unlink($path)) { 
        echo "Файл удален"; 
    } else {
        echo "Ошибка при удалении файла"; 
    };
    $response = $path;
    } else {
        $response = "false";
}

print_r(json_encode($response));
```

**В панели разработчика:**

> **Warning**:  unlink(D:/xampp/htdocs/editor/img/group_user_Медиаплеер Apple TV 32GB
>   4th generation (черный)_1.jpg): No such file or directory in
>   **D:\xampp\htdocs\management\ajax_scripts\img_delete.php** on line
>   **22**
>
> **Ошибка при удалении файла** "D:/xampp/htdocs/editor/img/group_user_\u041c\u0435\u0434\u0438\u0430\u043f\u043b\u0435\u0435\u0440
>   Apple TV 32GB 4th generation
>   (\u0447\u0435\u0440\u043d\u044b\u0439)_1.jpg"

Может, кто-нибудь знает решение такой проблемы, так как много в интернете подобных вопросов, но решения не нашел пока.

***UPD:***

Права доступа устанавливаю так:

```
if (chmod($path, 0740)) {
    echo "Права доступа для {$path} изменены"; 
} else {
    echo "Не удалось установить права для {$path}";  
};
```

Теперь скрипт возвращает это:

> **Права доступа для** D:/xampp/htdocs/editor/img/group_user_aМоноблок
>   Apple iMac Pro 27 с дисплеем Retina 5K_1.jpg измененыФайл
>   удален"D:/xampp/htdocs/editor/img/group_user_a\u041c\u043e\u043d\u043e\u0431\u043b\u043e\u043a
>   Apple iMac Pro 27 \u0441
>   \u0434\u0438\u0441\u043f\u043b\u0435\u0435\u043c Retina 5K_1.jpg"

Но забавно то, что файл то не удаляется из папки.

Comment: Достаточно ли прав на удаление файла? Правильный ли путь `$path` к файлу? У вас там `substr`, может в итоге слэш теряется какой-нибудь?

Comment: sabstr для того, чтобы убрать ковычки. Путь верный. Дополню сейчас основной пост тем как установил права доступа. Сейчас внезапно всё "удаляется". По крайней мере, скрипт об этом заявляет, но по факту ничего не удаляет.